# jQuery - removing an alert stop code from working

Tags: javascript, jquery

The code below works, but there is an issue with it.

That issue is that unless the alert(this.href); - (about line 11) is in the code the following function does not work.

```
//There are pages which make up 2 chapters in this content
//We shall attempt to grab all the links from these pages
var c;
var chapters = new Array();
chapters[0] = "original/html/0/ID0EFJAE.html";  

//Loop through each page of links
$.each(chapters, function(key, value) { 
    $("#theContent").append("<div class='chapterindex" + key + "'>working</div>");
    $(".chapterindex" + key).load(value + " .content");     

    alert(this.href);

    $(".chapterindex" + key + " div.link a").each(function(intIndex) {
            alert(".chapterindex" + key);
        });
    });
```

If I take the first alert out of line 11 then the last alert doesn't fire. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: May need to add some synchronicity `setTimeout(0)` instead of alert

Comment: Timing! Maybe the first alert blocks the javascript just long enough for the data to finish loading :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The delay that the `alert` is causing is allowing the data in your `load` call to load. I suspect that when you remove the `alert` the data does not load in time.

Try using a callback with your `load` call, something like (code not tested) -

```
$(".chapterindex" + key).load(value + " .content",function () {
        $(".chapterindex" + key + " div.link a").each(function(intIndex) {
            alert(".chapterindex" + key);
        });
});
```

Comment: So... use a callback function in `load`?

Answer (score 1):

The first alert is probably giving the load function enough time to finish so when you take it out the load function is not done when its trying to fire your second alert.